# How to get customized quarter of the year in Java?

Tags: java

The requirement is:

Completed in Q1 2012 – Jan 1st to and including April 1st.  (for Q1-2012 only)

Completed in Q2 2012 – April 2nd to and including July 1st

Completed in Q3 2012 – July 2nd to and including Oct 1st

Completed in Q4 2012 – Oct 2nd to Jan 1st (next year)

So far: 
`Calendar cal Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);`

`cal.setTime(date);`

`int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);`

`int quarter = (month / 3) + 1;`

But how do I get to include the April 1st in the first quarter and so on? That's where I turn blank.

I'm a bit at lost on how to do this and I'm stuck at it for a while now. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Could you provide some code done? More explanation about the requirement? If it is homework put the tag homework :)

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Well I used Calendar and so far: Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
cal.setTime(date);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int quarter = (month / 3) + 1; But how do I get to include the April 1st in the first quarter and so on? That's where I turn blank.

Comment: @user1292124 Please move the code sample from the comment to the question.  Code samples in comments are nearly impossible to read.

Comment: FYI, Java 8 and later includes the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends those classes to include classes such as `Quarter` and [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-). Generally speaking, you may find these handy. But they do not let you define your own altered meaning as asked here in this Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simplest idea would be to check if `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` equals 1 and `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)` equals 4, 7 or 10

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  Public String getQuarter(month){
       return "Q-" + ((int) (month-1)/3+1)
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't actually meet the requirements. Note for example that April 1st is part of the first quarter.

Comment: this is useful in some other cases